# Xdebug not working with supervisor as background runner

Tags: xdebug, supervisord, php-7.2

I currently have an issue that I don't really understand.
Here's the situation:

I'm running PHP7.2 in an Debian based box under Vagrant and Parallels on an Mac.

Config for Xdebug:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.24.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log="/home/vagrant/base/log/xdebug.log"
```

Calling the Symfony CLI app works fine.
But as soon as I call it over supervisor Xdebug doesn't respond as it should.
I tried several things but failed.

In PhpStorm I get this message:

> Cannot find file '/VMPATH/console' locally.
>   To fix it, set server name by environment variable PHP_ID_CONFIG and restart debug session

but I can't really find any help in the net on how to fix this issue.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add the line

```
environment=PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=PHPSTORM"
```

to your supervisor config block. Example:

```
[program:my_worker]
directory={{API_PATH}}
command={{API_PATH}}/my_worker.php "verificationWorker.php"
environment=PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=vagrant"
user=www-data
autostart=false
autorestart=true
```

Detail [here](http://yutaf.github.io/xdebug-remote-cli-debugging-with-vagrant-and-phpstorm/#php-ide-config-environment-variable)

And make sure you execute background script by php with installed xDebug extension.